# Call to a member function prepare() on null, unsure why

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I am getting the error Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null when I do the following call:

```
include_once(createMySQL.php);
$mySql = new createMySQL();
$conn = $mySql->makeSQLConnection();
$entry = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO thisTable (val1) VALUES (:val)");
$entry->bindParam(":val", $val);
$entry->execute();
```

This is my createMySQL class

```
class createMySQL{

    function makeSQLConnection(){
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect(){
        $name = "localhost";
        $db = "thisDatabase";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$name; dbname=$db; charset=UTF8", $username, $password);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die("PDOException:" . $e->getMessage());
        }
        //echo "success";
        return $conn;
     }
}
```

I am unsure why I am getting the following error. Does any one have any insight into this?

Comment: Your `makeSQLConnection()` method does not have a `return` keyword.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is... exactly what you're doing, calling function on null.

Let's have a look and try to find the cause!

You're calling

```
$entry = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO thisTable (val1) VALUES (:val)");
```

Let's see what $conn is then.

```
$conn = $mySql->makeSQLConnection();
```

All right, $conn is assigned to return value of $mySql's (createMySQL's class) makeSQLConnection function, let's take a look at it.

```
function makeSQLConnection(){
    $this->connect();
}
```

Hmm, it does not return anything. In this case the return value of function becomes null if you assign it to anything.

We found the error cause by tracing the error back.

For the most simple fix try adding `return` before `$this->connect();`

Comment: Gotta say, pretty well explained. Love when  people put such diligent answers :) +1

Comment: Agreed, I like it.

Comment: Wow... can't believe I skipped over that. Thank you.